# Can't open chrome inspector with javascript prompt is running

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log, inspector

I'm trying to open the Chrome inspector to see the console log and I can't.

It works very well with Firefox but not with Chrome.
The chrome development tools is enabled and works well when there is no prompt or alert pop up running.

I have a little program in which I have a prompt that asks the user to give a number.

Explanations for the user are in the console(`console.log("xxxx")`), so when the page is loaded and the prompt is on the screen, the user would have to open the inspector window to see what choice he/she should make.

Here is my code:

```
console.log("1\n2");
var saisie = prompt("What is your choice");
alert(saisie);
```

I would like the user to see the console log before they answer the prompt.

Comment: My advice would be to not use functionality that became outdated 10 years ago. Why not just provide the user an interactive web page?

Comment: Thank you all !
I'm a student at Openclassrooms and the very first exercice to learn js need to have interactions by prompt. Explanations for user and answer have to be shown in console, that's why i need that.
I've seen that i can refresh the page, close the window, open firebug without any problems in Firefox, but none of these works in chrome, and my "teacher" would like to have it on Chrome!
I trully know that alert and stuffs like that must not be used as a correct interaction with user. So i still have the problem !
Thanks again to everybody for your speed and your kindness !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.console` to access and interact via javascript with the debug console. Then you can pipe its contents to a div on the page.

Answer (score -1):

`alert` is blocking, which is why people tell you not to use it (or leave snarky comments to that effect). 'Blocking' means that nothing else can happen: it literally hijacks the entire tab. Meaning that you can't, say, open chrome devtools without dismissing the alert first. I have no idea how this is actually working in FF.

Pro-tip: don't *ever* use `alert`. Ever. Use a modal dialog, iframe, whatever. Don't use `alert`.